# Simple PHP recursion - why am I getting out of memory?

Tags: php, memory-management

So I am having a problem with memory out message...

I have a class (controller) with index method...something like this:

```
function index($parent=0){
    $this->__set_all_cats();
    foreach($this->CATS as $CAT){
        ...

        if($CAT["parent_id"] == $parent) $this->__set_all_sub_cats($CAT["id"]);
        ...
    }
}  



function __set_all_cats(){
    $CATS = ...get array from db
    foreach($CATS as $CAT){
        $this->CATS[$CAT["id"]] = $CAT;
    }
}

function __set_all_sub_cats($cat_id, $start = 1){
    if($start) $this->subs=array();
    $this->subs[] = $cat_id;

    $CAT = $this->CATS[$cat_id];
    $parent = $CAT["parent_id"];

    foreach($this->CATS as $C){
        if($C["parent_id"] == $parent){
            $this->__set_all_sub_cats($C["id"], 0);
        }
    }
}
```

where $this->CATS is an array fetched from DB with around only 3000 rows...

each row looks something like this

```
Array(
   [id] => 18674
   [importer_id] => 6
   [parent_id] => 0
   [category_id] => 1
   [category_name] => Category name
   [category_slug] => category0slug
   [private_category_id] => 0
   [trader_category_id] => 951
)
```

So not a big deal...and I've set php_ini to use 128M ... and I am getting:

> **Fatal error**:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) in **D:\root\app\my.controller.php** on line **186**

my goal is to get the list of parent cats that will have another firled called is_set of boolean type... the is_set value is TRUE when ALL of the children (and self) have trader_category_id set to other than 0...

so that's why I need to get all of the children for each parent cat...

**CAN it be done in db query (mysql) alone?**

Comment: I am sorry... never bothered to "ACCEPT" an answer once I got what I needed... shame on me! I will do it right away ;) Thanks for your time fellas!

Comment: hm... I reviewed once again my questions and the acceptance is correct... sadly I never got an useful answers from those questions that don't have acceptance. But seems you OZ_ have a lot of time on your hands checking this numbers! Good for you

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal "Pressuring"? It's just critic, don't overrate it. DS_web_developer, sorry if it was "harmful", but it's really annoying when users don't even taking 1 second of their time to say "thanks" for answer. Sometimes it takes 30-50 minutes to write an answer (especially with code).

Comment: @OZ_: You're doing it again. Please stop that. Answers should be accepted when they solve the original problem (and the OP has indicated that this has not happened on his other questions yet), not to satisfy the thirst for recognition that people like you seem to enjoy so much.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal do you think you know me enough to write "people like you"? Hate this phrase. You can't understand me even in this comments, so don't even try to judge. If you never have wasted hour to answer which wasn't even commented after all - you can't understand me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to specify under what conditions should the function stop and return.

**EDIT**

You have an error in your code logic it seems:

Lets say the first member of the array `$this->CATS` that was placed in `$CAT` is this:

```
Array(
      [id] => 1
      [parent_id] => 0
      ...
     )
```

The very first call to `__set_all_sub_cats($CAT["id"])` will have `1` as the `id` and `0` as the parent. `$this` refers to the original object (I assume this is the one with `id` equal to `0`).

Then `__set_all_sub_cats()` has a line like this:

```
foreach($this->CATS as $C)
```

So basically you are going over the `$this->CATS` array once again. But you never created another instance of your class. You are still using the original object

**EDIT**

The other answer explains it better

Comment: hm, I didn't.
The function should stop ONLY after cycling all the (preset) $this->CATS. Hence I am in a class scope, so the goal is not to return a value from a function but to SET a classes property ($this->subs)

Answer (score 0):

```
$CAT = $this->CATS[$cat_id];
$parent = $CAT["parent_id"];

foreach($this->CATS as $C){
    if($C["parent_id"] == $parent){
```

Problem seems to be there.  `$CAT` is still in `$this->CATS` (you never actually remove it) so you end up trying to set the sub categories for the same category constantly.

Comment: Hm... don't get your point. $this->CATS has ALL the cats (all the tree)...with all the data

I am trying to set $this->subs with ALL the CURRENT descendants....with only ids